# copy text on unselect, not on select

Tags: xorg, clipboard

Most of my copy/paste needs are spent replacing text.
I love the middle-mouse copy/paste feature of *nix systems, and I use it a lot, but it is annoying that, when pasting, I always have to click before, or after, the text I want to replace, paste, then select the text to remove, and press delete.
I can use normal copy-paste (ctrl-c,ctrl-v), but middle mouse is so much quicker and universal (works in terminals, etc).

I know this is a petty request, but I am wondering if there would be a way so selected text would get clipboarded only after I unselect it, in which case I could simply:

- select text to copy
- move to other window or to other place in text file
- select text to remove
- paste, and thus replace the text to remove in one sweep

Comment: It's almost impossible, I already have tried doing this and wasn't successful. It is almost impossible because there is one way to do this, to compile the Kernel and the OS yourself editing the code to turn Ctrl+V shortcut to be Middle-Mouse click. But I think you are not that crazy to try that...

Comment: I figured, but I thought maybe a clipboard manager could take over, for example, add the selected text to clipboard then restore previous selection